# AX2012 RouteOpr form shows all RouteOpr entries for a single ressource instead of the specific ones

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

My problem is that we **inserted some routeOpr** with the following logic (embedded in a job, see below) and now the RouteOpr form **shows all the routeOpr entries** in the RouteOpr Form no matter which ressource was selected.

Can someone please explain what the "**RouteOpr**" form is supposed to to if it is called via

```
'Organisation administration' / 'Area page' -> select a Ressource and click on 'Applicable for' / 'Operations'
```

[image]
[image]

With some debugging I already found out what the query for the form is, but I don't understand why the form isn't just showing the routeOpr entries for the specific ressource.

```
    RouteOpr                        routeOpr;
    WrkCtrRouteOprActivity          wrkCtrRouteOprActivity;
    WrkCtrActivity                  wrkCtrActivity;
    WrkCtrActivityRequirementSet    wrkCtrActivityRequirementSet;
    WrkCtrAbility                   wrkCtrAbility;
    WrkCtrActivityRequirementView   wrkCtrActivityRequirementView;

    changeCompany('someCompany')
    {
        WHILE SELECT routeOpr
            EXISTS JOIN wrkCtrRouteOprActivity
                WHERE routeOpr.RecId == wrkCtrRouteOprActivity.RouteOpr
                    EXISTS JOIN wrkCtrActivity
                        WHERE wrkCtrRouteOprActivity.Activity == wrkCtrActivity.RecId
                            EXISTS JOIN wrkCtrActivityRequirementSet
                                WHERE wrkCtrActivity.RecId == wrkCtrActivityRequirementSet.Activity
                                    NOTEXISTS JOIN wrkCtrActivityRequirementView
                                        WHERE wrkCtrActivityRequirementSet.RecId == wrkCtrActivityRequirementView.ActivityRequirementSet
                                            NOTEXISTS JOIN wrkCtrAbility
                                                WHERE wrkCtrActivityRequirementView.AbilityType == wrkCtrAbility.AbilityType
                                                   && wrkCtrActivityRequirementView.AbilityRecId == wrkCtrAbility.AbilityRecId
                                                   && (((wrkCtrAbility.LevelValue >= wrkCtrActivityRequirementView.MinimumLevelNeeded)))
                                                   && ((wrkCtrAbility.WrkCtrId == 'someWrkCtrId'))
                                                   && ((wrkCtrAbility.ValidFrom <= systemDateGet())
                                                   && ((wrkCtrAbility.ValidTo >= systemDateGet())))
                     {
                         Debug::printDebug(strFmt("%1 %2 %3", routeOpr.OprId, routeOpr.WrkCtrIdCost, routeOpr.ItemRelation));
                     }
    }
```

### **I think that I made some mistake and/or forgot something in my job, maybe someone can help me.**

```
select forUpdate route;
select forUpdate routeOpr;
select forUpdate wrkCtrActivityResourceRequirement;
select forUpdate wrkCtrActivityRequirementSet;
select forUpdate wrkCtrActivityRequirement;


route.clear();
route.RouteId      = routeVersion.RouteId;
route.OprNum       = 10;
route.OprNumNext   = 0;
route.OprId        = oprId;
route.Level        = 1;
route.AccError     = 1.00;
route.insert();


routeOpr.clear();
routeOpr.ItemCode          = TableGroupAll::Table;
routeOpr.ItemRelation      = routeVersion.ItemId;
routeOpr.RouteCode         = RouteAll::Route;
routeOpr.RouteRelation     = routeVersion.RouteId;
routeOpr.OprId             = route.OprId;
routeOpr.ProcessPerQty     = 1.00;
routeOpr.FormulaFactor1    = 1.00;
routeOpr.WrkCtrIdCost      = ressource;
routeOpr.COL_UnitId        = "HMIN";
routeOpr.ProcessTime       = str2num(time);
routeOpr.RouteGroupId      = "SOLL=IST";
routeOpr.ToHours           = 0.0002;
routeOpr.insert();


wrkCtrActivityRequirementSet = routeOpr.activityRequirementSet();
wrkCtrActivityRequirementSet.selectForUpdate(true);
//wrkCtrActivityRequirementSet.LoadPercent = 100;
//wrkCtrActivityRequirementSet.Quantity    = 1;
wrkCtrActivityRequirementSet.update();

wrkCtrActivityRequirement.clear();
wrkCtrActivityRequirement.ActivityRequirementSet     = wrkCtrActivityRequirementSet.RecId;
wrkCtrActivityRequirement.RelationshipType           = WrkCtrActivityRequirementType::Resource;
wrkCtrActivityRequirement.UsedForJobScheduling       = NoYes::Yes;
wrkCtrActivityRequirement.UsedForOperationScheduling = NoYes::Yes;
wrkCtrActivityRequirement.insert();

wrkCtrActivityResourceRequirement.clear();
wrkCtrActivityResourceRequirement.setActivityRequirement(wrkCtrActivityRequirement.RecId);
wrkCtrActivityResourceRequirement.WrkCtrId = ressource;
wrkCtrActivityResourceRequirement.insert();
```

Comment: Never seen this style of update/inserts before... `select forUpdate route;` looks unnecessary if you are going to _insert_ instead of _update_. `select forUpdate wrkCtrActivityResourceRequirement;` without filters will select _all_ rows. I am _guessing_ the related update() statement will only update the first row (fingers crossed it did not update all of them). Also, your inserts and updates are related, add a transaction (`ttsBegin;`, `ttsCommit;`) around them.

Comment: That's not a style, it's **WRONG**. Do not do it and DELETE that. What it is doing is selecting the entire table for update with a random single record in the buffer. Then his `.clear()` line is clearing all of the field data from that random record. After that he's replacing the fields with his own data, then the `insert()` command *might* actually save him. I'd have to do some testing with AX to see what actually happens because this should NOT be done. I *think* the insert would ignore all of that and create a new record and replace the variable with the single inserted buffer.

Comment: Thank you both for your comments
@AlexKwitny imagine the `select forUpdate` lines are deleted, would the job be correct?, 
I made a quick test and it looks like your assumption was correct, the insert just creates a new record, 
so for me it looks like the job works but I'm not 100% sure about the `wrkCtrActivityRequirementSet`
which gets selected with `wrkCtrActivityRequirementSet = routeOpr.activityRequirementSet();` and then updated ...  
Maybe you could also tell me what the form is supposed to do?

Comment: @Thomas - I don't remember everything about routes off hand and I don't have an environment with good data to repro, but this is pretty simple stuff if you have a debugger. That method just runs a simple query and returns the result. With the debugger, you can just step in and examine the query (or manually) examine it via regular code window. If it doesn't return a result, then it hasn't found the buffer. To say if your code is right/wrong is difficult because I don't have the data to check really. Debugger & table browser would be super easy to figure out though.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the incorrect job, the actual error was that I didn't set the value of the `wrkCtrActivityResourceRequirement.ResourceDataAreaId` field.

So i made a job which sets the field like this

```
wrkCtrActivityResourceRequirement.ResourceDataAreaId = curExt2dataareaid(tableNum(WrkCtrTable));
```

and now the correct entries are shown.

(I didn't notice the error because the field was set `visible = No,` so it was not shown in the table browser.)